# Animating submit button's value change

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am submitting a form in my php application using the `.ajax()` function.  If the form is successful I am changing the submit buttons text from "SUBMIT" to "MESSAGE SENT SUCCESSFULLY".

It works great, but I'd like to animate the button's value change instead of it just 'popping' to the next value.

I saw the `fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()`, and `fadeTo()` functions but I don't think these would work.

How can I do this?  Thanks!

Comment: My guess is you would probably have to animate between two different elements (with the second being disabled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gZWby/

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
<input type="button" id="sent" value="MESSAGE SENT SUCCESSFULLY" style="display: none;"/>

$(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(1000, function(){$('#sent').fadeIn(1000);});
    });
});
```

Gives you the general idea. If you wanted to do a crossfade, my thought would probably be put them in DIV's and fade the DIV's while also positioning them to overlay.

**UPDATED**

Crossfading:

http://jsfiddle.net/gZWby/1/

```
#submit, #sent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#sent {
  display: none;
}

<div id="submit">
 <input type="button" value="SUBMIT"/>
</div>
<div id="sent">
 <input type="button" value="MESSAGE SENT SUCCESSFULLY"/>
</div>


$(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(1000);
        $('#sent').fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

With `disabled="disabled"`

http://jsfiddle.net/gZWby/2/

```
<div id="submit">
 <input type="button" value="SUBMIT"/>
</div>
<div id="sent">
 <input type="button" value="MESSAGE SENT SUCCESSFULLY" disabled="disabled"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach I came up with:

```
$('form').submit(
    function(){
        $(this).trigger('success');
        return false;
    });

$('form').bind('success',
               function(){
                   var submitValue = 'form success!';
                   $('<input id="temp" type="submit" value="'+ submitValue +'" />')
                       .text(submitValue)
                       .appendTo('body');
                   var width = $('#temp').outerWidth();
                   $(this)
                       .find('input:submit')
                       .animate(
                           {
                               'color':'transparent'
                           }, 1500,
                                function(){
                                    $(this).val(submitValue);
                                })
                       .animate(
                           {
                               'color': '#000',
                               'width': width
                           }, 1500);
                   $('#temp').remove();
               });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xWwXT/1/).

This is, almost certainly, ridiculously verbose. And could be far more concise...but it works well enough...if that's any consolation.

Comment: Are you serious? (Maybe it's just the formatting, which gives me vertigo)

Comment: @Jared, bear in mind that I chose to animate,and cross-fade, the values in the submit button, rather than fadeOut and fadeIn a new one. ...otherwise, yeah: it's nowhere near as concise as it should/could be.